# js2xmlparser not parsing numeric keys

Tags: json, node.js, xml

I am trying to create xml file from json object, using js2xmlparser. My code is as below:

```
var js2xmlparser = require("js2xmlparser");

var data = {
    "product": "painting",
    "88CODE": "-2"
};

console.log(js2xmlparser.parse("product", data));
```

But it throws an error as below:

```
E:\projects\xml-generator\node_modules\xmlcreate\lib\nodes\XmlElement.js:94
                throw new Error("name should not contain characters not"
                ^

Error: name should not contain characters not allowed in XML names
    at XmlElement.set [as name] (E:\projects\xml-generator\node_modules\xmlcreate\lib\nodes\XmlElement.js:94:23)
    at new XmlElement (E:\projects\xml-generator\node_modules\xmlcreate\lib\nodes\XmlElement.js:72:20)
    at XmlElement.element (E:\projects\xml-generator\node_modules\xmlcreate\lib\nodes\XmlElement.js:218:23)
    at parseObjectOrMapEntry (E:\projects\xml-generator\node_modules\js2xmlparser\lib\main.js:130:33)
    at parseObjectOrMap (E:\projects\xml-generator\node_modules\js2xmlparser\lib\main.js:152:13)
    at parseValue (E:\projects\xml-generator\node_modules\js2xmlparser\lib\main.js:220:9)
    at parseToDocument (E:\projects\xml-generator\node_modules\js2xmlparser\lib\main.js:249:5)
    at Object.parse (E:\projects\xml-generator\node_modules\js2xmlparser\lib\main.js:265:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\projects\xml-generator\server.js:16:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

I want one of the node to be <88CODE>. How do i resolve this issue ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml standard states that an xml element name must start with a letter or an underscore... thus your error.  Your data property `88CODE` must be renamed.

So the short answer is if you want an element to have the name `88CODE`... you'll get this error.  Consider renaming the element to something else... perhaps `_88CODE`

**Xml Element Naming Rules**

- Element names are case-sensitive.
- ***Element names must start with a letter or underscore.***
- Element names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
- Element names can contain letters, digits, hyphens, underscores, and periods.
- Element names cannot contain spaces.

[sorry.. w3schools reference :)](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp)

Answer (score 0):

this will work fine or change the name of the second field so it must start with an letter or _

```
var js2xmlparser = require("js2xmlparser");

var data = {
"product": "painting",
"_88CODE": "-2"
};

console.log(js2xmlparser.parse("product", data));
```